# IMPORTXML in Google Sheets cannot seem to dive multiple spans

Tags: html, xpath, google-sheets

I have a fun spreadsheet for playing with PowerBall (potential) winnings.  I discovered that I could use IMPORTXML to auto-fill the cash value of the current jackpot.  But something changed and I am trying to fix it, but there's a problem:

`=IMPORTXML(A4,A?)` where A4= `https://www.powerball.com/powerball-prize-estimate` and A? = the XPATH.

The problem is that the XPATH comes to this: `//*[@id="block-winningnumbersmodule"]/div[2]/div[2]/span[3]`

The Full XPATH is: `/html/body/div[2]/div/header/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/span[3]`

The relevant div[2] looks like this from the page:

```
<div class="estimated-jackpot">
        <span class="estimated">Estimated Jackpot</span>
        <span class="number"></span>
        <span class="cash-value" data-value="Cash Value:"></span>
      </div>
```

The second span is empty and I can't access the third span.

I solved this issue for myself in that the same info turned out to be elsewhere in the page. The old XMLPATH changed very little:
From:
`/html/body/div[2]/div/main/div/div[1]/article/div/div[3]`

To:
`/html/body/div[2]/div/main/div/div[2]/article/div/div[3]`

I switched to the, presumably, less likely to change randomly:
`//div[@class="field_prize_amount_cash"]`
Which lands me the same place.

But I continue with the question because I think it's still valid...why can't I get past the first `span`?

These are the XPATHs that I tried and the results for each:

`//*[@id="block-winningnumbersmodule"]/div[2]/div[2]/span[3]`   **#N/A**    XPATH
`/html/body/div[2]/div/header/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/span[3]` **#N/A**    Full XPATH
`//*[@id="block-winningnumbersmodule"]/div[2]/div[2]/span`  **Estimated Jackpot**
`/html/body/div[2]/div/header/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/span`    **Estimated Jackpot**
`//div[@class="estimated-jackpot"]` **Estimated Jackpot**
`//span[@class="estimated"]`    **Estimated Jackpot**
`//span[@class="number"]`   **#N/A**    This is an empty span
`//span[@class="cash-value"]`   **#N/A**    This is what I am wanting
`//*[@id="block-winningnumbersmodule"]/div[2]/div[2]/span[1]`   **Estimated Jackpot**   For completeness' sake
`//*[@id="block-winningnumbersmodule"]/div[2]/div[2]/span[2]`   **#N/A**    Maybe it doesn't count the empty span?  Poop!

So, help?  That I don't need anymore except to scratch an itch :)

Well I figured it out! "The relevant div[2] looks like this from the page:" showed empty spans! Looking at the elements they were all filled in...they never made it to the page source! The part I found later in the page was in the elements AND the source.  "There's your problem, right there!"

```
  <div class="field_next_draw_date">
          <time datetime="2021-05-16T02:59:59Z">2021-05-16T02:59:59+0000</time>

      </div>

  <div class="field_prize_amount">
          $183 Million
      </div>

  <div class="field_prize_amount_cash">
          $127.4 Million
      </div>
```

Look!  Numbers! Not nothing!  So when I was getting #N/A it was because I was trying to read nothing.  IMPORTXML is cool, *and* it will read nothing as nothing every time!

Now I leave this here as...a cautionary tale? ...a reminder? (of what?)

I know... A funny story about how the asking of a question, if done thoroughly, giving *all* information to help those answering with every conceivable piece of information so that they are *able* to answer, can wind up leading you to your own answer.

I guess.

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Great and funny example. While putting all pieces  in the question, you answered your own question and learned a lot.

Comment: So, you don't really have a question - is that right? You had a problem, then you solved your problem, and then you posted the above - correct?

Comment: @JohnH sort of...
I had a problem.  
I was writing the post to ask for help with it.
I solved the problem, but hadn't yet found the answer to the question.
Then I found the answer to my question.
Then I tried to explain all that and posted this anyhow...so yeah, it's solved.

Comment: Perhaps if you were a bit less verbose you would be more effective. What is your question?

Comment: @JohnH My verboseness led me to the answer.  That turned out to be the whole point.  Sorry I confused you.